# R Error: anyNA() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'closure' Calls

Tags: r

getting this error only when compiling Rmarkdown to a .pdf.  When I run my actual R code, I get no errors. Reproducible error:

```
library(dplyr)

data <- read.table('http://data.princeton.edu/eco572/datasets/brazilDeathRates1999.dat', header = TRUE)
data <- mutate(data, n = c(diff(age), 0))
kfnax <- read.dta("http://data.princeton.edu/eco572/datasets/kfnax.dta")
data<- inner_join(data, kfnax, by="age")
data <- rename(data, a = nax)  # for simplicity
data <- mutate(data, q_males = n * males/(1 + (n - a) * males), p_males = 1 - q_males)
data <- mutate(data, q_females = n * females/(1 + (n - a) * females), p_females = 1 - q_females)

#makes the last values 1 and 0 respectively for death probability
data[last, c("q_males","p_males")] = c(1, 0)
data[last, c("q_females","p_females")] = c(1, 0)
```

It appears the error is triggered on this line:
`data <- mutate(data, q_males = n * males/(1 + (n - a) * males), p_males = 1 - q_males)`

Comment: `last` is a function, not a `variable` (here). What are you intending it to be?

Comment: `data[last, c("q_males","p_males")] ` should get the value of the last row for the columns `q_males` and `p_males`.  I replace those two values with 1 and 0.

Comment: Try `data[nrow(data), c("q_males","p_males")]`. The first argument to `[` must be of type `logical` or `integer`, not a function (which is being referred to as a *closure* here).

Comment: Thank you!  You saved me so much stress!  I had defined `last <- nrow(data)` and accidentally deleted the line.  `last` was stored in my R environment, so the program had no errors upon compilation... only during Rmarkdown.

Comment: *Reproducibility* often means clearing the global environment of variables and trying again. (I've done that many many times.) BTW: this is one impetus for naming variables uniquely from function names ... the use of `data`, though very common, has also caused similar errors.

Comment: Great points.  Thank you so much for the advice.